# I want to create a filter for the query string is this possible?

Tags: query, rewrite-rules

I have spent the last few days working on and researching this question and have found no solution.

Basically I want to replace the query string which wordpress parses in order to query the database.

So for example, I want to say if the url is:

```
www.mysite.com/support/question
```

go to

```
www.mysite.com/another/page
```

I know I can setup fancy rewrite rules using the `add_rewrite_rules` filter, but this is over complicating the situation. I don't want to go down this route, all I want to do replace the exact request i.e. `support/question` with `another/page`

Is there a simple way to pass a different query string to wordpress?

Comment: maybe htaccess redirect?

Answer (score 1):

To at least answer the title of your question, the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter may be useful. From the Codex:

> This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but
>   before the actual query is run.
>
> The pre_get_posts action gives developers access to the $query object
>   by reference (any changes you make to $query are made directly to the
>   original object - no return value is necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for maybe you can try this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple JavaScript to achieve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    if ( window.location == "www.mysite.com/support/question" ) {   
        window.location = "www.mysite.com/another/page"     
}
</script>
```

Comment: This solution isn't SEO friendly, and causes an extra, unnecessary page load. JavaScript is rarely the right choice for redirects.